# Write a domino effect

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, dominoes

Using the fewest Unicode characters, write a function that accepts three parameters:

- Total number of dominoes
- `n`th affected domino
- Topple direction of the affected domino (`0` or `L` for left, `1` or `R` for right)

Once a domino is toppled, it must also topple the remaining dominoes in the same direction.

You should output the dominoes with `|` representing a standing domino and `\` and `/` representing a domino toppled to the left and right respectively.

### Examples

`10, 5, 1` should return `||||//////`
`6, 3, 0` should return `\\\|||`

Comment: Should the third parameter be a string or will a bool/int do like 0:left , 1:right?

Comment: Your example suggests that if there are 10 dominoes, and 5 are knocked right, we should display *six* of the ten dominoes knocked over.

Comment: @algorithmshark I think we should show the result if the fifth domino is knocked right.

Comment: @rybo111 Can you allow the third parameter to be an int as that can make comparison operations shorter. Simply `if(third_parameter)` instead of `if(third_paramter=='l')`

Comment: Can we choose the order of the parameters?

Comment: Alright, use whichever parameter order and the direction can be an int or a string

Comment: And my example is correct: if you knock over the 5th domino, to the right, it also knocks over the remaining dominos to the right.

Comment: Shouldn't right make `//////||||` ? Your example doesnt start at the beginning...

Comment: @Martijn The example parameters are `10, 5, 'r'` - this translates to: __There are `10` dominos. Knock the `5`th one to the `r`ight__. This means the 5th domino becomes knocked over (`/`) as does everything _after_ it. However, if you change the `r` to an `l`, the output would be `\\\\\|||||` because when you knock a domino left it would knock over everything _before_ it instead.

Comment: IMO a bit weird principle for dominos. I Interpreted it as `10 dominos, 5 have allready fallen in the direction R`. Guess I'll have to update my code

Comment: @Martijn Well, the principle of the domino effect is that one change causes others to change. I'd rather specify one change than specify all the changes

Comment: Mine was assuming the items where still falling, more like s snapshot. But updated my code

Comment: @Martijn if it's any consolation, I interpreted as you did as first as well ^.^

Answer (score 14):

### Ruby, 38 (46) characters

```ruby
e=->n,k,r{k-=r;'\|'[r]*k+'|/'[r]*n-=k}
```

This function takes the direction as an integer (`1` for right, `0` for left). A function that takes a string is 8 characters longer:

```ruby
d=->n,k,r{n-=k;r<?r??\\*k+?|*n :?|*~-k+?/*-~n}
```

Usage examples:

```ruby
puts e[10, 5, 1] # or d[10, 5, 'r']
||||//////
puts e[10, 5, 0] # or d[10, 5, 'l']
\\\\\|||||
```

Comment: why are there only 5 dominoes knocked left in the second example?

Comment: @ClydeLobo Because you start at position 5 and knock the domino to the left, which in turn knocks over the 4 dominoes to its left, for a total of 5. In the first example, starting at position 5 knocks over 6 dominoes: The one at position 5 plus the *5* to its right.

Answer (score 8):

## J - <strike>32</strike> 26 char

J can't handle more than two arguments without using a list, and it can't handle non-homogenous lists without boxing. So having the input as a list of three integers is ideal. The parameter order is the reverse of the standard one: 0 for left or 1 for right, then position, then total number of dominoes.
The reason for this is because J will end up going through them right-to-left.

```
{`(('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.)/
```

Here's what's going on. `` F`G/ `` applied to a list `x,y,z` will evaluate `x F (y G z)`. `y G z` constructs both possible ways the dominoes could have toppled, and then  `F` uses `x` to select which of the two to use.

Below is a back-and-forth with the J REPL that explains how the function is built together: indented lines are input to the REPL, and responses are flush with the left margin. Recall that J evaluates strictly right to left unless there are parens:

```
   1 ] 3 (]) 10            NB. ] ignores the left argument and returns the right
10
   1 ] 3 (] 1+i.) 10       NB. hook: x (F G) y  is  x F (G y)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   1 ] 3 (>: 1+i.) 10      NB. "greater than or equal to" bitmask
1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1 ] 3 (-@>: 1+i.) 10    NB. negate
_1 _1 _1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   1 ] 3 (<: 1+i.) 10      NB. "less than or equal to"
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 ] 3 ((-@>:,:<:)1+i.) 10          NB. laminate together
_1 _1 _1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0  0  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
   1 ] 3 (('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.) 10   NB. turn into characters
\\\|||||||
||////////
   1 { 3 (('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.) 10   NB. select left or right version
||////////
   {`(('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.)/ 1 3 10  NB. refactor
||////////
   {`(('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.)/ 0 3 10
\\\|||||||
```

At the expense of a few characters, we can make the order the standard order: just append `@|.` to the end of the function:

```
   |. 10 3 1
1 3 10
   {`(('|/\'{~-@>:,:<:)1+i.)/@|. 10 3 1
||////////
```

Adapting this to work with a string argument for direction would be much more costly, however.

Comment: I know it's been a _while_ since you wrote this answer, but the way it is structured is very cool. I really like how you made use of gerunds and `/` and also the way you build two outputs and select the desired one. I guess I feel like this lacks the recognition it deserves.

Comment: What @cole said, I was awed.

Answer (score 8):

**Haskell, 70**

```haskell
f R i l=(i-1)#'|'++(l-i+1)#'/'
f L i l=i#'\\'++(l-i)#'|'
(#)=replicate
```

assuming there is a type *Direction*, which has constructors *R* and *L*.

Answer (score 7):

### PowerShell, 66

```
filter d($n,$k,$d){"$('\|'[$d])"*($k-$d)+"$('|/'[$d])"*($n-$k+$d)}
```

Probably the same idea every one else had.

- Takes either 0 or 1 as the direction parameter (for left and right, respectively)

Answer (score 6):

### Golfscript (44 <s>53</s>)

My first ever Golfscript program. Took me way longer than it should have and can probably be done in a smarter, more concise way (I'm sure someone will prove that :) ):

```
:d;:j;:^,{:x j<d&'\\'{x^j)->d!&'/''|'if}if}%
```

A sample input is `10 5 0`.

Ungolfed:

```
:d;:j;:^      # save input in variables and discard from stack, except total length ^
,             # create an array of numbers of length ^
{             # start block for map call
  :x          # save current element (= index) in variable
  j<          # check whether we are left of the first knocked over domino
  d           # check whether the direction is to the left
  &           # AND both results
  '\\'        # if true, push a backslash (escaped)
  {           # if false, start a new block
    x^j)->    # check whether we are on the right of the knocked over domino
    d!        # check whether the direction is to the right
    &         # AND both results
    '/'       # if true, push a slash
    '|'       # if false, push a non-knocked over domino
    if
  }
  if
}%            # close block and call map
```

Comment: Proof done ;-) although I am not happy with my solution yet.

Comment: Some tips: you may choose `d` to be `0`/`1` instead of `'l'`/`'r'` which gives you some shorter code. Otherwise, if you store `d'l'=` in a variable oyu may use it instead of the second comparison with `d`. In the term `x i j` you can save both whitespaces if you use a non-alphanumeric variable name instead of `i`.

Comment: @Howard Thanks for the tips! I chose `'l'`/`'r'` because at the time I didn't see yet that we are free to use integers. The non-alphanumeric trick is slick, thanks! Maybe I'll update the answer later.

Answer (score 4):

### JS (ES6) - <s>79</s> <s>74</s> <s>72</s> <s>65</s> 62

thanks to @nderscore!

The 3rd param is a boolean (0: left / 1: right)

```
d=(a,b,c)=>"\\|"[a-=--b,c].repeat(c?b:a)+"|/"[c].repeat(c?a:b)

// Test
d(10,3,1); // => "||////////"
d(10,3,0); // => "\\\\\\\\||"
```

Comment: this entry could be a reference card for ECMAScript 6 :D

Comment: @bebe haha, and it's not even its final form. ES6 can be very dirty.

Comment: 65: `d=(a,b,c)=>"\\"[r="repeat"](!c&&a-b+1)+"|"[r](--b)+"/"[r](c&&a-b)`

Comment: great! I also found this crazy thing but it's longer (67):  d=(a,b,c,d=a-b+1)=>"\\|"[c].repeat(c?b-1:d)+"|/"[c].repeat(c?d:b-1)

Comment: I don't think repeat aliasing is worth. `[r='repeat'][r]` 15 chars. `.repeat.repeat` 14 chars

Comment: @edc65 but .repeat is used three times in the first function. That's why I made the alias

Comment: 62: `d=(a,b,c)=>"\\|"[a-=--b,c].repeat(c?b:a)+"|/"[c].repeat(c?a:b)`

Comment: @nderscore hey. you beat me once again. Stop that. lol :) thanks, it's awesome.

Answer (score 4):

## Python - 45 <s>52</s>

This requires `1` for right and `0` for left.

```py
x=lambda n,k,d:'\\|'[d]*(k-d)+"|/"[d]*(n-k+d)
```

Here's a version that takes `r` and `l` correctly, at **58**:

```py
def x(n,k,d):d=d=='r';return'\\|'[d]*(k-d)+"|/"[d]*(n-k+d)
```

Some usage examples...

```
>>> print(x(10,3,0))
\\\|||||||
>>> print(x(10,3,1))
||////////
>>> print(x(10,5,1))
||||//////
>>> print(x(10,5,0))
\\\\\|||||
>>> print(x(10,3,0))
\\\|||||||
```

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, <strike>28</strike> 23 characters

```
'\\'@*2$'|/'*$-1%1>+@/=
```

Arguments on top of stack, try [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=MTAgNSAxCgonXFwnQCoyJCd8LycqJC0xJTE%2BK0AvPQ%3D%3D&run=true):

```
> 10 5 1
||||//////

> 10 5 0
\\\\\|||||
```

Comment: Amazing. Love to learn from all these golfscript solutions :)

Answer (score 3):

**Python2/3 - 54**

That last added on rule was quite nice (the 0/1 instead of 'l'/'r'). Made mine actually smaller than the existing python solution. 0 is left, 1 is right

```python
def f(a,b,c):d,e='\|/'[c:2+c];h=b-c;return d*h+e*(a-h)

# Usage:
print(f(10,5,1)) # => ||||//////
print(f(10,5,0)) # => \\\\\|||||
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
(n%k)b=["\\|/"!!(b-div(k-b-c)n)|c<-[1..n]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NDoIwFIT3nuJBJGmTFiHGHb2BrlwWFi0/8aWlIVBdmN69Fo3Lmflm5qE2M1obI3GFoVrIvG3DKc8yovmAL2K45j11NPQNl3VZuq6LkyAFPcwKHQiY1XKD5envfr06OIKcYMP3COjQo7Iw4ArhZzUc5JnBhUFddeybpNEqyaT@/A6ln72Qrj4)

Takes input like `(%) n k b` for `n` dominos, `k`'th domino toppled, direction `b`.

Finds the character at each position `c` ranging from `1` to `n` by using an arithmetic expression to compute the character index 0, 1, or 2.

Test cases taken from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173928/20260).

---

**[Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 44 bytes**

```hs
(n%k)b=take n$drop(n+n*b+b-k)$"\\|/"<*[1..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY1NDoIwGET3nmJCIOFfCHFHb6Arl6WLEiA2LZ@k1I3h7hU0Lt/Mm8xDrno0xvuYIp30zEk9gsLBPpeYMkr7rC90EgZdt52DNuV1WZLwE4uj5DRLRWCY5XLD8nJ3Z6@EEHzCqt4jFCmnpMGgLLZf1BbgTY5LjroS@bdpC17tuNPfP6T95hgI4T8)

An interesting strategy that turned out a bit longer. Generates the string `"\\|/"<*[1..n]` with `n` consecutive copies of each symbol, then takes a slice of `n` contiguous characters with start position determined arithmetically.

Answer (score 2):

### Python 2.7, <strike>68 65 61 59</strike> 58 chars

Use `d=1` for left and `d=0` for right

```
f=lambda a,p,d:['|'*(p-1)+'/'*(a-p+1),'\\'*p+'|'*(a-p)][d]
```

Note: Thanks to @TheRare for further golfing it.

Comment: Why not `d and'\\'...or'/'...`?

Comment: You could also do `('\\'...,'/'...)[d]`

Comment: @TheRare I would need two of those lists.

Comment: I don't think so. `f=lambda a,p,d:('|'*(p-1)+'/'*(a-p+1),'\\'*p+'|'*(a-p))[d]`

Comment: @TheRare  `Also, I don't think your code works when falling left.` Could you give a test case to prove?

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, <del>67</del> 65 Characters

```perl
sub l{($t,$p,$d)=@_;$p-=$d;($d?'|':'\\')x$p.($d?'/':'|')x($t-$p)}
```

Assign the first three params (total, position, direction as an integer [0 left, 1 right]). Extras go into the ether.
Subtract 1 from the position if we're headed right so the domino in position X is flipped, too.

Comment: replace `$p--if$d` with `$p-=$d` to lose two characters :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 61 <s>63</s>

**Edit** It was buggy - shame on me.

Not so different from @xem, but found it myself and it's shorter. Parameter d is 0/1 for left/right

```
F=(a,p,d,u='|'.repeat(--p),v='\\/'[d].repeat(a-p))=>d?u+v:v+u
```

**Test** In Firefox console

```
for(i=1;i<11;i+=3) console.log('L'+i+' '+F(10,i,0) + ' R'+i+' '+ F(10,i,1))
```

**Output**

```
L1 \\\\\\\\\\ R1 //////////
L4 \\\\\\\||| R4 |||///////
L7 \\\\|||||| R7 ||||||////
L10 \||||||||| R10 |||||||||/
```

Comment: Should it be `--p`?

Comment: @nderscore yes it should, got parameters wrong, silly me.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript, 46 characters**

Seems like cheating to do 0=l and 1=r but there is is.  Shrunk it with a little recursion.

```
f=(a,p,d)=>a?'\\|/'[(p-d<1)+d]+f(a-1,p-1,d):''
```

edit: missed an obvious character

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

*4 bytes saved thanks to [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96371/56656)*

```hs
f 0 b _=[]
f a b c=last("|/":["\\|"|b>c])!!c:f(a-1)(b-1)c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P03BQCFJId42OpYrTSERyEy2zUksLtFQqtFXsopWiompUapJskuO1VRUTLZK00jUNdTUSAISyf9zEzPzbAtKS4JLinzyVNIUDI0UjBUM/wMA)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>69</s> <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 58 bytes

```hs
(0!b)_=[]
(a!b)c|b==c=a!b$c+1|1>0="\\|/"!!c:((a-1)!(b-1))c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X8NAMUkz3jY6lksjEchKrkmytU22BTJVkrUNawztDGyVYmJq9JUUFZOtNDQSdQ01FTWSgKRm8v/cxMw824LSkuCSIp88FQ1DI0VjTcP/AA)

Not a very complex answer but it beats both of the existing Haskell answers.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>75</s> <s>68</s> <s>61</s> 57 bytes

An anonymous function. I'll post a fuller explanation if there is interest.

```r
function(t,n,d)cat(c("\\","|","/")[(1:t>n-d)+1+d],sep="")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDkAwEADQ3Vc0N93FiTbCIOFH1CCtJpYj1ObfD8Mb36lp0HRLyNsumFk4UlgyBgTvgeH51EATuj6PUkUqXRlnvtZjACBN6Cyblo2j4m/gBahI2LFp2FhSfQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 51 bytes

```hs
f a b c=("\\|"!!c<$[1..b-c])++("|/"!!c<$[b-c..a-1])
```

`a` = number of dominoes, `b` = 1-based index of the touched one, `c` = direction (`0` is left and `1` is right).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY29DoMgAIRf5SQOGoFKmm76Bu3UERmQakqKxihdGt6dYn/G@@673F1vj8G5GEdo9DBtQboukCwzTS4F5z0zqqyqgoTDDybCuWZClXHSdkaLSS8XLE9/9et5Rg45YrOvAXa23mqHm10RvqhhkEeKE4WoFf00DZN1iin9/V1K1/tAqfgG)

Comment: Defining an infix operator also works for more than two inputs: `(a#b)c= ...`.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP, 89 Characters**

```
function o($a,$p,$d){for($i=0;$i<$a;$i++)echo$d==0?($i+1>$p)?'|':'\\':($i+1<$p?'|':'/');}
```

Just because I love PHP.

**EDIT:** The following code does the same.

```
function dominoes ($number, $position, $direction) {
    for ($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
        if ($direction==0) {
            if (($i+1) > $position) {
                echo '|';
            } else {
                echo '\\';
            }
        } else {
            if (($i+1) < $position) {
                echo '|';
            } else {
                echo '/';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a more detailed version?

Comment: @Martijn , I edited my post to include one.

Comment: Now I can see what it does. Nothing too fancy, but +1 :)

Comment: Thanks! @NPlay 's solution(s) look fancy though!

Comment: a couple of golfing tips: 1) Unnecessary parentheses at `($i+1>$p)`. 2) Rewriting your ternary expression to `$d?($i+1<$p?'|':'/'):$i+1>$p?'|':'\\'` saves another 3 bytes. Or just remove `==0` and invert directions. 3) With `$i++<$a` you can remove `$i++` from the post condition and use `$i` instead of `$i+1` (-6 bytes). 4) `$i=0` is not necessary; but you´d have to suppress notices (option `--n`)  if you remove it (-4 bytes).

Comment: @Titus thank you, feel free to edit and claim credit!

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 64

```
function f($a,$b,$c){for($w='\|/';++$i<=$a;)echo$w[$c+($i>$b)];}
```

A simple loop, and echo-ing the character.

Generates a `Notice: Undefined variable: i`, here's another version silenting the error (65 characters) :

```
function f($a,$b,$c){for($w='\|/';@++$i<=$a;)echo$w[$c+($i>$b)];}
```

And a version withtout any error (69 characters) :

```
function f($a,$b,$c){for($w='\|/',$i=0;++$i<=$a;)echo$w[$c+($i>$b)];}
```

---

Other functions in PHP :

`sprintf` / `printf` padding

```
function f($a,$b,$c){printf("%'{${0*${0}=$c?'|':'\\'}}{$a}s",sprintf("%'{${0*${0}=$c?'/':'|'}}{${0*${0}=$a-$b+$c}}s",''));}
```

padding via `str_pad` / `str_repeat` functions

```
function f($a,$b,$c){$f='str_repeat';echo$f($c?'|':'\\',$b-$c).$f($c?'/':'|',$a-$b+$c);}
function f($a,$b,$c){echo str_pad(str_repeat($c?'|':'\\',$b-$c),$a,$c?'/':'|');}
```

using both `printf` and `str_repeat` functions

```
function f($a,$b,$c){printf("%'{${0*${0}=$c?'|':'\\'}}{$a}s",str_repeat($c?'/':'|',$a-$b+$c));}
function f($a,$b,$c){$w='\|/';printf("%'$w[$c]{$a}s",str_repeat($w[$c+1],$a-$b+$c));}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala 75 characters

```
def f(l:Int,p:Int,t:Char)=if(t=='l')"\\"*p++"|"*(l-p) else "|"*(l-p):+"/"*p
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam - 20

```
q~
:X-_"\|"X=*o-"|/"X=*
```

The main code is on the second line, the first line is just for getting the parameters from the standard input (otherwise you need to put the parameters in the code).

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

**Examples:**

```
12 4 1
|||/////////

8 5 0
\\\\\|||
```

**Explanation:**

`:X` stores the last parameter (0/1 direction) in variable X
`-` subtracts X from the knock-over position, obtaining the length of the first sequence of characters (let's call it L)
`_` makes a copy of L
`"\|"X=` gets the character to use first: `\` for X=0 and `|` for X=1
`*` repeats that character L times
`o` prints out the string, removing it from the stack
`-` subtracts L from the number of dominoes, obtaining the length of the second sequence of characters (let's call it R)
`"|/"X=` gets the character to use next: `|` for X=0 and `/` for X=1
`*` repeats that character R times

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp

This won't win in a code golf, but it highlights Common Lisp's justification format directive:

```
(lambda (n p d &aux (x "\\|/"))
   (format t "~v,,,v<~v,,,v<~>~>" n (aref x d) (+ d (- n p)) (aref x (1+ d))))
```

The arithmetic isn't bad:  `n` is the total number of dominoes; `p` is the position of the first toppled domino; `d` is either `0` or `1`, representing left and right (as allowed in the comments), and is used as an index into `x`;  `x` is a string of `\`, `|`, and `/`.  The format string uses two (nested) justification directives, each of which allows for a padding character.  Thus:

```
(dotimes (d 2)
  (dotimes (i 10)
    ((lambda (n p d &aux (x "\\|/"))
       (format t "~v,,,v<~v,,,v<~>~>" n (aref x d) (+ d (- n p)) (aref x (1+ d))))
     10 (1+ i) d)
    (terpri)))

\|||||||||
\\||||||||
\\\|||||||
\\\\||||||
\\\\\|||||
\\\\\\||||
\\\\\\\|||
\\\\\\\\||
\\\\\\\\\|
\\\\\\\\\\
//////////
|/////////
||////////
|||///////
||||//////
|||||/////
||||||////
|||||||///
||||||||//
|||||||||/
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>23 21</s> 19 bytes

```
'|/\'{~{:-(>i.)~`-/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0G9Rj9Gvbqu2kpXwy5TT7MuQVf/f2pyRr6CRpqOlZKVZlF@ebGCqYKJgqGOgpmCIYgyBUIDHSsFQzMFYwWD/wA)

Input is a list of integers in the standard order.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
αα©„\|³è×¹®-„|/³è×J
```

I still have the feeling it's a bit long, but it works.. And better than the initial 23 bytes solution I had with if-else construction, which I quickly dropped..

Input order is the same as in the challenge: total length, index, `1`/`0` for left/right respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3MZzGw@tfNQwL6bm0ObDKw5PP7Tz0DpdIL9GH8L3@v/f0IDLlMsQAA) or [verify both test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/k5ukS6unpEvb/3MZzGw@tfNQwL6Ym8vCKw9MjDq3TBfJq9ME8r/86/w0NuEy5DLnMuIy5DAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
α                     # Take the absolute difference of the first two (implicit) inputs
                      #  i.e. 10 and 5 → 5
                      #  i.e. 6 and 3 → 3
 α                    # Then take the absolute difference with the third (implicit) input
                      #  i.e. 5 and 1 → 4
                      #  i.e. 3 and 0 → 3
  ©                   # Store this number in the register (without popping)
   „\|                # Push "\|"
      ³è              # Use the third input to index into this string
                      #  i.e. 1 → "|"
                      #  i.e. 0 → "\"
        ×             # Repeat the character the value amount of times
                      #  i.e. 4 and "|" → "||||"
                      #  i.e. 3 and "\" → "\\\"
         ¹®-          # Then take the first input, and subtract the value from the register
                      #  i.e. 10 and 4 → 6
                      #  i.e. 6 and 3 → 3
            „|/       # Push "|/"
               ³è     # Index the third input also in it
                      #  i.e. 1 → "/"
                      #  i.e. 0 → "|"
                 ×    # Repeat the character the length-value amount of times
                      #  i.e. 6 and "/" → "//////"
                      #  i.e. 3 and "|" → "|||"
                  J   # Join the strings together (and output implicitly)
                      #  i.e. "||||" and "//////" → "||||//////"
                      #  i.e. "///" and "|||" → "///|||"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 23 bytes

```
[-‹\|*₴+\/*,|-\\*₴+\|*,
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%5B-%E2%80%B9%5C%7C*%E2%82%B4%2B%5C%2F*%2C%7C-%5C%5C*%E2%82%B4%2B%5C%7C*%2C&inputs=0%0A3%0A6&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## C - 62 <strike>64</strike> ('l':left, 'r':right)

```
f(a,b,c){for(b=a-b;a--;)putchar(c&2?a<b?47:124:a>b-2?92:124);}
```

## C - 58 (0:left,1:right)

```
f(a,b,c){for(b=a-b;a--;)putchar(124-(a<b-!c?c*77:!c*32));}
```

recursive approach, but still, same length

```
f(a,b,c){a&&f(a-1,b,c)+putchar(124-(a<=b+!c?!c*32:c*77));}
```

awfully long (75) but most complex one (repeat function integrated into it)

```
f(a,b,c){c>1?a&&f(a-1,putchar(b),2):f(b+c,c?92:124,2)+f(a-b-c,c?124:47,2);}
```

Comment: This segfaults for me, probably because printf expects a `const char*` instead of an int (using `putchar` instead works). It also looks like this always knocks the dominoes over towards the right (i.e. for `10,5,'l'` it prints something like `||||\\\\\\ ` instead of `\\\\\|||||`).

Answer (score 0):

#### PowerShell (<s>107</s> 95)

```
filter d($a,$b,$c){-join(1..$a|%{if($_-ge$b-and$c){'/'}elseif($_-le$b-and!$c){'\'}else{'|'}})}
```

If we're allowed to treat the third parameter as an integer (0=l,1=r), then I can shave a little off here.

Test input:

```
d 10 5 r
||||//////
d 10 5 l
\\\\\|||||
```

Update:

```
d 10 5 1
||||//////
d 10 5 0
\\\\\|||||
```

If anyone by chance wants an explanation I will gladly add one. And as always I'm open to suggestions.

Original:

```
function d($a,$b,$c){-join(1..$a|%{if($_-ge$b-and$c-eq'r'){'/'}elseif($_-le$b-and$c-eq'l'){'\'}else{'|'}})}
```

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 181

```cpp
#define C(x) cin>>x;
#define P(x) cout<<x;
int n,k,i;char p;
int main(){C(n)C(k)C(p)
for(;i<n;i++){if(p=='r'&&i>=k-1)P('/')else if(p=='l'&&i<=k-1)P('\\')else P('|')}
return 0;}
```

Comment: You don't actually need to explicitly `return 0` from `main`.

Comment: It doesn't compile for me because cin and cout are not in the global namespace - what compiler are you using?  Also, `C(n)>>k>>p` would be shorted than `C(n)C(k)C(p)` wouldn't it? And if the define for P() could stringify the argument wouldn't that save characters for all the quotes?  And when you compare p to 'l' and 'r': 0 and 1 would be shorter - specifically >0 instead of =='r' and <1 instead of =='l' (assuming you are ok using numbers instead of r/l - if not <'r' is still shorter than =='l' and >'l' is still shorter than =='r')

Comment: @JerryJeremiah for cin and cout need "using namespace std".

Comment: I know but since it is only used twice it is shorter to qualify the functions.  Neither way works on my compiler without the include.

Answer (score 0):

### VBScript <strike>101</strike> <strike>95</strike> 74

Edit: Looks like a lot of answers accept bool directions. For char directions, replace `-d` with `+(d="r")` for a score increase of 6.

```
function f(a,p,d):for x=1to a:f=f+mid("/|\",3-d+(x>p),1):next:end function
```

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: @JesterBLUE Thanks for pointing that out. I re-coded and shortened it a bit, too.

Comment: That looks a lot nicer but it still isn't producing the right results.  Try Mid("\|/",1-d-(x>p+d),1).  (Also note that d is never explicitly converted to a boolean, so running f(10,4,1) will give funky results because the function relies on an implicit boolean to integer conversion.   Putting in a d=d<>0 would lock d down to 'true' or 'false'. It's not a problem here, though, because this is golf.)

Comment: @JesterBLUE I had to flip the symbol order to get this to work correctly. I didn't realize I broke the code when I allowed for "bool" directions.

Answer (score 0):

## C# 92('\':left, '/':right)

```c#
String d(int c, int p, char d){ String r="";for(int i=0;i<c;i++)r+=(i>=c-p)?d:'|';return r;}
```

Comment: Would be even shorter if you rename `result` and get rid of the additional whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

### AWK, <strike>76</strike> 61

```
{ORS="";for(i=1;i<$2;i++)print"|";for(i=$2;i<=$1;i++)print($3=="r"?"/":"\\")}
```

Usage:

```
echo 10 5 r | awk '{ORS="";for(i=1;i<$2;i++)print"|";for(i=$2;i<=$1;i++)print($3=="r"?"/":"\\")}'
```

Although I'm wondering if I can nest ternary operators to make this shorter (although I'm playing around in bash right now and it doesn't seem like you can).

**edit** -- shorter version:

```
{ORS="";for(i=0;i<$1;i++)print i<$2?"|":($3=="r"?"/":"\\");}
```

Comment: What about `{ORS="";for(i=0;i<$1;i++)print i<$2?"|":($3=="r"?"/":"\\");}`

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't think was possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - <strike>105,97</strike>, 96

```
 function a($r,$l,$f){$a=str_repeat('|',$l-$f);$b=str_repeat($r?'/':'\\',$f);echo$r?$a.$b:$b.$a;}
```

Example results:

```
a(true,10,4);  -> \\\\||||||
a(false,10,5); -> |||||/////
a(false,10,2); -> ||||||||//
```

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, <strike>81</strike> 85 characters

```
function e(a,b,c){l='repeat';d='|'[l](--a-b++);return c>'q'?d+"/"[l](b):"\\"[l](b)+d}
```

First time trying codegolf, was fun thanks :)

Comment: Might as well modify the function to be an ES6 function, as string repeat is ES6 (doesn;t work in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript - 85 chars

```
function d(a,b,c){for(r=c?"\\":"/",p="",b=a-b;a--;)p+=c?a<b?"|":r:a>b?"|":r;return p}
```

1 = Left, 0 = Right

```
d(10,3,1)
\\\|||||||
d(10,3,0)
||////////
d(10,7,1)
\\\\\\\|||
d(10,7,0)
||||||////
```

Answer (score 0):

**vb.net (~75c)**

```
Dim f=Function(l,p,d)(If(d="l",StrDup(p,"\"),"")& StrDup(l-p-If(d="l",1,0),"|")).PadRight(l,"/")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clojure, 81 chars**

```
(defn g[a,p,d](apply str(map #(nth "\\|/"(+(if(>= % (- p d)) 1 0) d))(range a))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES5) - 86 chars

```js
function f(a,p,d){r='';while(a-->p+1)r+='|';while(a-->=0)r=d>'q'?r+'/':'\\'+r;return r}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Autoit 245 Bytes

```
Local $1 = "",$dir = "l",$amout = 100,$pos = 33
for $i=1 to $pos
    if $dir = "r" then
    $1 = $1 & "|"
Else
    $1 = $1 & "\"

EndIf
next
for $i=1 to $amout-$pos
    if $dir = "r" then
    $1 = $1 & "/"
Else
    $1 = $1 & "|"
EndIf
next
ConsoleWrite($1 & @cr)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python <strike>71</strike> 59

```
def k(n,p,d):c,r='\/'[d],n-p;return[c*p+'|'*r,'|'*p+c*r][d]
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell (72)

Using guards and the characters `'r'` and `'l'` as directions:

```haskell
r=replicate;k a o d|d=='r'=r(a-o)'|'++r o '/'|d=='l'=r o '\\'++r(a-o)'|'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl : 66 characters

My first code golf submission! Thanks for the fun challenge.

```
sub k{($n,$p,$r)=@_;$n-=$p;$d=$r?"|"x--$p.'/'x++$n:'\\'x$p.'|'x$n}
```

Explanation with whitespace:

```
sub k{
  ($n,$p,$r) = @_;      # get function arguments: <# dominos> <position> <0=left, 1=right>
  $n -= $p;             # total number of dominos - position
  $d = $r ? "|"x--$p . '/'x++$n : '\\'x$p . '|'x$n
                        # if direction = 1, make pos - 1 '|'s and (total - position  + 1) '/'s
                        # if direction = 0, make pos '\'s and (total - position) '|'s
                        # return is the last action of the function, it returns the string in $d.
                        # Semicolon at end of line can be left off, as it is the last statement of the function
}
```

Example usage and output:

```
my $result = k(10,5,1); print "$result\n";
||||//////
my $result = k(10,5,0); print "$result\n";
\\\\\|||||
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 69

My first code golf submission, with Python in 69 characters:

```
def d(a,b,c):print "|"*(b-1)+"/"*((a+1)-b) if c else "\\"*b+"|"*(a-b)
```

Usage: d(10,5,1)

Comment: I know it's been 4 years since this was posted but you have a lot of extra whitespace involved in this answer.  White space is generally not required on the borders of quotes or parentheses.  Here is your code without the extra whitespace `def d(a,b,c):print"|"*(b-1)+"/"*(a+1-b)if c else"\\"*b+"|"*(a-b)`.  You could also use a lambda to make this shorter `lambda a,b,c:"|"*(b-1)+"/"*(a+1-b)if c else"\\"*b+"|"*(a-b)`.

Comment: Ooooookkkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 55 bytes

```php
for([,$c,$n,$d]=$argv;$c--;)echo"\|/"[$d+(++$i+$d>$n)];
```

- requires PHP 7.1 or later
- replace `[...]=$argv` with `list(...)=$argv` for PHP 5.5 or later
- for older PHP, insert `$s="\|/",` before that and replace the other `"\|/"` with `$s`.

Run with `php -nr '<code>' <total> <N> <numeric direction>` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/77eba673e317ad8d6a8b35371e3238f672577d4c).

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 15 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I'm sure this could probably be shorter but it's been a long day. Uses `0` & `1` for left and right.

```
ç| hW*VVçWg"\\/
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=53wgaFcqVlbnV2ciXFwv&input=NiwzLDA)

```
ç| hW*VVçWg"\\/     :Implicit input of integers U=total, V=n & W=direction
ç|                  :Repeat "|" U times
   h                :Replace the characters starting at 0-based index ...
    W*V             :W times V with ...
       Vç           :V times repeat ...
         Wg"\\/     :Index W into "\/"
```